# Angular2 n - getting invalid argument [object Object] ... for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular

I am getting an error trying to display he results of my service call.  The html page has an ngFor with the | async.  I can make the call, get the results, but receiving an error when trying to render the page.  I know the variable need to be an Observable for the async to work.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong and have tried several things.  Any insight is appreciated.

**Error Message:**
Invalid argument '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

**Variable Definition**

```
  public products:Observable<Product[]>;
```

**Call to Service**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.productService.load().subscribe(
      data => {
        // Set the products Array
        this.products = data['_embedded'].products;
      },
      error => console.log('Could not find product catalog.')
    );
```

}

**Service Call**

```
 load() {
    return this._http.get(`http://localhost:8000/products`).map(response => response.json());
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody *ngFor="let product of products | async">
          <tr>
            <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
            <td>{{product.materialNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
            <td>{{product.baseUom}}</td>
            <td>{{product.packageSize}}</td>
            <td>{{product.casePack}}</td>
            <td>{{product.weight}}</td>
            <td>{{product.height}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
```

**Data From Call**

[image: Data From Call]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Async` pipe needs an `Observable` rather then an `Array`.

In your case just try to remove `async`:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let product of products">
```

Also change variable definition:

```
public products:Array<Product> = [];
```

Explanation:
`array | async` does `subscribe` by itself.

The code

```
this.productService.load().subscribe(
  data => {
    // Set the products Array
    this.products = data['_embedded'].products;
  },...
```

transforms an `Observable` to `Array of Products`

**Update**: 
This already works in `async` manner: since `products` is an empty array, `ngFor` doesn't run. When `Observable` gets a response and populates data into `products`, a `change detection` round takes place and goes through `ngFor` again (now populating products)

Another weird thing I've noticed (I could be wrong):

`ngFor` very like should be on `tr`:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let product of products | async">
   ...
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

In this case you'll have multiple rows and just one `tbody`

Comment: Thanks, yes removing the async from the ngFor works, but I wanted to get things to work with the async ...   Thanks for your input