# Angular2 Unit testing Uncaught Error: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

Having problems runnign my unit test code, getting this error message when trying to run the test:

- Uncaught Error: Error in package:454:50:17 caused by: Invalid argument '[object 
  Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
  at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError

**dashboard.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { MockAF } from "../../providers/mockAf";
import { AF } from "../../providers/af";
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { SortOnLikePipe } from '../sort-on-like.pipe'
import { EditMessageModalComponent } from '../edit-message-modal/edit-
message-modal.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { MockModal } from '../edit-course-modal/mockEdit-course-
modal.component';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
  let routerStub;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  routerStub = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  };
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      DashboardComponent,
      SortOnLikePipe,
      EditMessageModalComponent,
     ],
    imports: [
      FormsModule,
    ],
    providers: [
      { provide: AF, useClass: MockAF },
      { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
      { provide: EditMessageModalComponent, useClass: MockModal },
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { queryParams: Observable.from([{ 
      course: "TDT4001" }]) }},
    ],
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This is where i use pipes in my code
**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let message of afService.messages | async | 
sortOnLike:'votes':false">
.....
</div>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ElementRef, ViewChild } from 
'@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AF } from '../../providers/af';
import { FirebaseListObservable, AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Bubble } from './bubble';
import { EditMessageModalComponent } from '../edit-message-modal/edit-
message-modal.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id.toString(),
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  constructor(public afService: AF, private router: Router, private route: 
  ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
      // Defaults to error if no query param provided.
      this.afService.setCourse(params['course'] || "error");
     });
  }
```

I have no clue on how to fix this problem, the funny thing is that it all worked. But when i got home to continue testing i got this error. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121908/angular2-n-getting-invalid-argument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe

Comment: I have, didn't help me much. My code works when i run ng serve, i get this error message when i run ng test

Comment: just add import 'rxjs/Rx';`
 instead of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; on your spec.ts
`

Comment: Then i get to two new error messages: 1. Observable is not defined, and 2. Cannot create the component DashboardComponent as it was not imported into the testing module!.