# Get uid and iterate over an array of objects using Angular4 and Fireabse

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, chat, angularfire

I am building a 1-1 chat using Angular4 and Firebase and I am pretty new to Angular.
In order to initiate a conversation, I am trying to display all available users form '/users' subcollection. So, I need to get user/{user.uid}/username.

This is my chat.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { UserSessionService } from '../_services/user-session.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  other_users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  user_id: any;
  from: any;
  msgVal: string = '';


  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase, public logged_user: UserSessionService ){ }

    ngOnInit() {

      this.from= this.logged_user.getFirebaseUid();
      this.user_id= this.logged_user.getFirebaseUid();

      this.items = this.af.list('/personalMessages', {
      query: { limitToLast: 5  }
    });

    this.other_users= this.af.list('/users');

  }

  findChat(){
    this.other_users= this.other_users;
     this.user_id = this.user_id;    
  }

    chatSend(theirMessage: string) {     
      this.items.push({ text: theirMessage, from: this.logged_user.getFirebaseUid(), isRead: false, timestamp: + new Date()  });
      this.msgVal = '';
      this.user_id = this.user_id;
      this.other_users= this.other_users;
  }

}
```

And this is my chat.component.html:

```
<div class="users-chat-container" *ngFor="let other_user of other_users| async">
      <div id="circle" style="background-color:pink;">        
      </div>
     <br/> <a href="#">{{other_user.username}}  </a>    

    </div>


    <div class="chat-container" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <div id="circle" style="background-image:url( http://www.ics.forth.gr/mobile/female.png);">        
      </div>
     <br/> <a href="#">{{item.from}}  </a>    
      <p>{{item.text}}</p>
    </div>
     <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..." (keyup.enter)="chatSend($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="msgVal" />
```

How can I iterate over the array of objects I get from '/users' collection?  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need use  `ForkJoin`. ForkJoin will take users list as input and fire parallel request for all users list

try some thing like this

```
this.af.list('/users')
            .mergeMap((users) => {
               if (users.length > 0) {

                return Observable.forkJoin(
                    users.map((user) => this.af.database
                        .object(`user/${user.$uid}/username`)
                        .first()
                    ),

                    (...values) => { // here you can assign username 
                        users.forEach((user, index) => { user.username = values[index]; });
                        return users;
                    }
                  );
          }
          return Observable.of([]);
            });
```

more info about forkJoin
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it worked.  I could see the results in my console. But here, at this point, hoe can I display results in my chat.component.hmtl?  With *ngFor="let other_user of other_users| async" I get an error in my console saying that Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'.  Have you faced this problem too or can you help with it? Thank you!

Comment: post your console log result.check this link also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121908/angular2-n-getting-invalid-argument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe

Answer (score 1):

You need an array for *ngFor. With object.keys you can create an array of the objects. In the example below I have done this with players from a group, coming as objects from firebase.

```
private getPlayersPerGroup(group: Group) {
    this.playersInGroup = [];
    if (group["players"]) {
        Object.keys(group["players"]).forEach((key) => {
            this.groupService.getPlayerById(key).then((player) => {
                this.playersInGroup.push(player);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A method like this I applied for other object and object of objects.                                                                               
                                                                                                                     `this.whatever= this.personal_conversations.forEach(pc => {
       let q = this.changenameafter;      
      this.changenameafter = pc.map(x => {return x; });
      this.changenameafter2 = this.changenameafter.map((entry) =>{
       return entry[Object.keys(entry)[0]];
      });
    }); `