# Filter pipe not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying filter data from firebase by user input. I have created a pipe to handle this but I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

my html is:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="search proerties by post-code" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let property of properties | propertyFilter:searchTerm">
        {{property.post_code}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

ts file as follows:

```
export class SearchPropertiesComponent implements OnInit {
public properties: PropertyModel[];
routing = environment.routing;
searchTerm: string;

  constructor(private _property: PropertyManageService) {
    this._property.getAllProperties().valueChanges().subscribe(properties => {
      console.log(properties);
      this.properties = properties;
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and finally my pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'propertyFilter'
})
export class PropertyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(properties: PropertyModel[], searchTerm: string): PropertyModel[] {
  if(!properties || !searchTerm) {
    return properties;
  }
  return properties.filter(property =>
    property.post_code.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1); //ERROR HERE
}

}
```

I have tried changing post_code to other fields within the object I am receiving but I am still having the same problem. I guess this means the information is never actually getting as far as this for it to be undefined?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try add `async` pipe. It could try to handle data not fetched yet.

Comment: @Sergey where do I add that pipe?

Comment: inside `*ngFor`

Comment: post_code is of what type ? if its number/null then it doesn't have indexof method available on it

Comment: @AbineshDevadas returns a string

Comment: Does error remain if you add `*ngFor="let property of properties | propertyFilter:searchTerm | async"`?

Comment: @Sergey that returns : "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: `properties` is an object?

Comment: @Sergey yes it is

Comment: @Sergey it is an array of objects

Comment: There is a similar problem about async pipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121908/angular2-n-getting-invalid-argument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe If you solve this I think everything should work

Comment: Wrap your `*ngFor` in an `*ngIf="properties?.length"`

Comment: @GeoAstronaute I've done that, no change?

Comment: @Sergey his answer on that one does not really work in the same way as mine

Comment: The only thing I can recommend now is to use some extension to debug app or use console log just to understand what **really** comes to pipe